# Create dictionary with a list as key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a list of numbers and want to add them to an existing dictionary with the value 0. What's the easiest way of doing this? Seems so easy but I can't find any clean way of doing this. For example:

```
key = [1,2,3]
value = 0
dict  = {}
... one more line of code if possible ...

>>>dict
{(1,2,3):0}
```

Comment: Dictionary keys have to be hashable, lists are not because they're mutable.

Comment: Your sample output uses a tuple as the key. You can convert the list to a tuple and use it as the key.

Comment: If you want the `dict` as your sample output: `{(*key,):0}`

Comment: `key = [1,2,3]` => `key = (1,2,3)` if you know that the key is a tuple just create a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your list to a tuple like this:

```py
key = [1,2,3]
value = 0
d = {tuple(key): value}

>>>d
{(1,2,3):0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output uses a tuple as the key. So convert the list to a tuple.

```
d[tuple(key)] = 0
```

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type/function.